# I wanna develop an INIT- how to set up dev env

Tags: init

I wanna make an init, and so I'm gonna need to get a very basic system on a VM probably. What is the best way to go about doing that? I also saw that it might be possible doing this with a docker container?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a test VM/container with a working normal `init`, then work to *replace* that `init` with your custom one.

Basically, in a VM, you would place your custom `init` into e.g. `/sbin/custominit`, and then you could boot the VM with a kernel boot parameter `init=/sbin/custominit` to see how it works. By removing the boot parameter you could then compare the results with a standard `init`. Once you get it working acceptably like that, you could make a custom initramfs that'll use your custom `init` instead of the standard one (if applicable).

Eventually you could package your custom `init` so that your custom package will satisfy all the same package manager dependencies as the distribution's normal `init` package, and then install your custom one as a package, and remove the normal `init` package from the system.

Comment: yeah I was aware of this, but is there a distro that's better to use than another for this? does it even matter?

Comment: You might want to choose a distro whose init is similar to the one you wish to develop (if possible), to minimize the work needed to change configuration files/start-up scripts to suit your new init.